# Translate Pine Script(TradingView) To C#

Tags: pine-script

I don't understand the following command properly,
For Example :

```
if isHighLast ? price > pLast : price < pLast
    // Command
else
    // Command
```

If I want to write the equivalent of this command with C# code, it is like this, is it correct?

```
if(isHighLast == true)
{
    if(price > pLast)
        // Command
}
else
{
    if(price < pLast)
        // Command
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you wrote is correct but C# also has a ternary operator.

```
if(isHighLast ? (price > pLast) : (price<pLast))
{
  // Command
}
else
{
  // Command
}
```